# How to find the A and B where B value can be A value using mysql

Tags: mysql

Table structure

```
 sl_ no     A                 B            TOTAL
  1         DUDE             SAM         5
  4         COOL             DUDE        8
  6         KEWL             COOL        8
  8         ROCK             KEWL        10
```

How to fetch the value if i give `SAM` it should be able to fetch the `TOTAL` of `DUDE` which is in column `B`

eg:

```
SAM =DUDE 
    DUDE=COOL
    COOL=KEWL
    KEWL=ROCK
```

OUTPUT IF I GIVE `SAM` IT SHOULD FETCH THE `DUDE TOTAL=8`

Comment: your question does not make sense

Comment: After your update I am even more confused :)

Comment: So... What have you tried so far? Or is this mySQL for beginners?

Comment: @Jivings m confused how to write query for it... it is not mysql for beginners :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question here's the request you need:

```
SELECT table_o.TOTAL 
    FROM <your_table> AS table_i 
        LEFT JOIN <your_table> AS table_o ON table_i.A = table_o.B
WHERE table_i.B = ?
```

You join your table on itself using the columns A and B, and then select the total of the outer table you joined.

Comment: Still wondering how this dude answer it !! You really deserve a medal

Answer (score 1):

It was hard to understand... You can do it like this :

`SELECT B.TOTAL FROM <tblName> as A, <tblName> as B WHERE A.B = B.A AND A.B = ?`

(the first parameter is, in your example, `SAM`).